# Is there a way to point a controller method to an arbitrary view?

Tags: playframework

I want to have multiple controller methods point to a single view.

the **Messages** controller will have two methods, *newMsg* and *newMsgWithParent* that each point to app/views/newMsg.html, and the view will handle the (very simple) logic differentiating the two input forms.

How can I do this, if possible?

Edit: Flipping through the API, you can use play.mvc.Controller.renderTemplate for this problem.

Comment: Can you post an answer then mark as accepted in a couple of days. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods. You can use

```
render(templateName, args...);
```

or

```
renderTemplate(templateName, args...);
```

I prefer the second method, as although they work in exactly the same way, I believe the second to be clearer and therefore better practice.